# LINQ OrderBy().ThenBy() not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlite

I am converting a project of mine from using an SQL Server based Entity Framework model, to using a local SQLite database.  So far everything is going well, but for some reason I am not able to sort queries on multiple columns.  For example:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection("test3.db"))
{
    var query = from a in db.Table<Account>()
        where a.Inactive == false
        orderby a.AccountName, a.AccountNickname
        select a;
    foreach (var account in query)
    {
        accounts.Add(account);                    
    }
}
AccountsGrid.ItemsSource = accounts;
```

Gives me the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'ThenBy'`, but if I change the ordering to:

```
orderby a.AccountName
```

then the query works fine.  I have also tried using `.OrderBy(a => a.AccountName).ThenBy(a => a.AccountNickname)` but I get the same error.  I am already including `using System.Linq;` but ReSharper is telling me that the using directive is not required, so that seems fishy also.  Does anyone have any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: what `db.Table<Account>()` type?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the SQLite wrapper that I'm using.  Rather than using the `System.Linq` implementation of .OrderBy(), it appears to be using it's own implementation.  I'm using sqlite-net.

Comment: @Grundy, `db.Table<Account>()` is the underlying SQLite table of `Account` objects returned from the database.

Comment: I'm surprised that you can just call `db.Table<Account>` like this at all. Looking at the LinqConnect documentation, I'd have expected it to need a context class instead... where is that `Table` method defined? (If you hover over it, it should say whether it's an extension method or not.)

Comment: i mean what type of collection like `IQueryable`, `IEnumerable` or something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet, it is saying the `Table` method is `TableQuery<Account> SQLiteConnection.Table<Account>()`

Comment: you can try add `System.Linq` namespace and change `db.Table<Account>()` to `db.Table<Account>().AsQueryable()` or `db.Table<Account>().AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @dubstylee: It's possible that I'm looking at the wrong SQLiteConnection - where did you get the library from, and what namespaces are you using?

Comment: I'm using the SQLite wrapper from here: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: you use not extensions method, you use member method for this class `TableQuery<T>`. So in class not implementation for `ThenBy`

Comment: @Grundy, it looks like using `.AsQueryable()` did the trick!  Thanks, I'm not sure how much more I could bang my head against the wall.

Comment: @dubstylee: No *don't* use `AsQueryable`. That will be basically doing all the ordering in .NET instead of in your database. (I'd expect the database to be able to do a quicker job of it.) The `AsQueryable` call you're using isn't supported directly by the SQLite implementation... it's just using the fact that `TableQuery<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet possibly `AsEnumerable` better in this case?

Comment: @Grundy: No, absolutely not - in both cases you'd be doing all the ordering in .NET rather than in the database. (Or rather, using AsEnumerable might be *slightly* better, but still missing the point of LINQ.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs), it seems the author doesn't understand LINQ properly:

- They haven't provided a `ThenBy` method, but instead they're collecting multiple orderings with multiple `OrderBy` calls
- They haven't exposed the table as an `IQueryable<T>` implementation (which is why you don't need `using System.Linq`) - while this is a *valid* approach, it's a pretty unusual one

I would personally be pretty nervous about using this - the fact that it's "organized" as three huge source files is slightly alarming too. You may want to try using [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect) instead - although I haven't used that, either.

If you *do* want to stick with the implementation you're using, I *suspect* that this would work - but it wouldn't work with other LINQ providers:

```
var query = from a in db.Table<Account>()
    where a.Inactive == false
    orderby a.AccountName
    orderby a.AccountNickname // Warning! Not portable!
    select a;
```

Normally having two `orderby` calls like this would be a *really, really bad idea* - but it seems that that's what the LINQ provider wants in this case.

Comment: I was previously using the `System.Data.SQLite` nuget package by the SQLite development team, but it didn't seem to be as flexible.  When I came across the `sqlite-net` project, it seemed to be more user friendly, but maybe I didn't give the official one a good enough chance.  I will look into LinqConnect as well!  Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to view the methods available in a package?  I am trying to determine if what I'm trying to achieve is feasible using the `System.Data.SQLite` package rather than the `sqlite-net` package I am currently using.  When I was using `System.Data.SQLite` before, it was a lot more tedious to accomplish anything, but I may have just not known its capabilities.

Comment: @dubstylee: Well you'd need to try to find the documentation, basically. Or you can just use Intellisense to explore the API, of course.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know, I gave LinqConnect a shot today, and it is leaps and bounds better than the sqlite-net that I was using before.  It supports full LINQ-like behavior, as far as I can tell.  Thanks the the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
    In Linq Query

var query = (from a in db.Table<Account>()
            where a.Inactive == false
            orderby a.AccountName ascending, a.AccountNickname descending
            select m);

      In Lambda Expression

var query = db.Table<Account>().where(a => a.Inactive == false).OrderBy(a => a.AccountName).ThenByDescending(a =>a.AccountNickname);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, you are merely showing two equivalent expressions.